# Invalid object name 'master.dbo.MSreplication_options' when restoring DB

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, replication, backup, restore, transactional-replication

I've tried Googling for an answer to this but have got nowhere.

I have one SQL Server instance whose replication is set up to be a publisher and a distributor of `FooDatabase`.  I have a second instance whose replication is set up to be a subscriber of `FooDatabase` on the first instance.  Replication updates work.  What I want to do is backup the subscription `FooDatabase`, delete it on the subscriber instance, and restore the backup.  However, when I do this and try to restore the backup, I get the following error:

> Restore failed for Server 'DAVEG1525-162'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Invalid object name 'master.dbo.MSreplication_options'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

I've checked and `dbo.MSreplication_options` does exist as a system table in the `master` database on the *production* instance, but not on the *subscription* instance.

My questions are: if it doesn't exist on the subscription instance, why is it being included on the backup made from the subscription instance of SQL Server? and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: At this point, are you able to run 'ALTER DATABASE <name> ONLINE'?

Comment: @dev_etter Yes (well actually `ALTER DATABASE <name> SET ONLINE`), and it brings the DB online in single user mode.

Comment: You could try using sp_removedbreplication to remove all replicated objects from the database, which should clean up all the residual stuff from the publisher copy. However I'm not sure how it would affect the subscription going forward. It may have to be re-configured. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188734.aspx

Comment: @dev_etter Why would there be anything from the publisher copy?  I'm both backing up from and restoring to the subscription database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the table `master.dbo.MSreplication_options`, amongst various other replication-related tables, are supposed to exist on any SQL Server 2008 r2 install whether or not you've set up replication.  Somehow the one on my SQL Server instance got dropped.  I eventually found this handy script on Google (cached!) which 'fixes up' various replication things, including recreating `master.dbo.MSreplication_options` if it doesn't already exist:

```
-- ***************************************************************************
-- Copyright (c) 1997 - 2003 Microsoft Corporation.
-- All Rights Reserved
--
-- @File: ReplicationFixup.sql
--
-- Purpose:
--  Procedures/extended stored procedures (XPs)/functions that are owned by replication and are created on master database
--  
-- Notes: Created 2001/02/07 10:28 (RMak)
--
-- History:
--
--     @Version: Yukon
--
-- @EndHeader@
--
exec sys.sp_configure 'update',1
reconfigure with override

set ANSI_NULLS off

use master
go

-- Make sure that we remove procedures that got accidentally installed in 
-- master by an 80 sp2 QFE
if object_id('dbo.sp_MSreplremoveuncdir', 'P') > 0
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSreplremoveuncdir

if object_id('dbo.sp_MSdeletefoldercontents', 'P') > 0
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSdeletefoldercontents

-- drop extended procedures that were created in master

if object_id('xp_mergexpusage', 'local') is not null
    execute sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'xp_mergexpusage'

if object_id('xp_mergelineages', 'local') is not null
    execute sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'xp_mergelineages'

if object_id('xp_mapdown_bitmap', 'local') is not null
    execute sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'xp_mapdown_bitmap'

if object_id('xp_ORbitmap', 'local') is not null
    execute sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'xp_ORbitmap'

if object_id('xp_firstonly_bitmap', 'local') is not null
    execute sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'xp_firstonly_bitmap'

if object_id('xp_varbintohexstr', 'local') is not null
    execute sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'xp_varbintohexstr'

if object_id('xp_intersectbitmaps', 'local') is not null
    execute sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'xp_intersectbitmaps'

if object_id('xp_displayparamstmt', 'local') is not null
    execute sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'xp_displayparamstmt'

if object_id('xp_printstatements', 'local') is not null
    execute sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'xp_printstatements'

if object_id('xp_makecab', 'local') is not null
    exec sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'xp_makecab'

if object_id('xp_unpackcab', 'local') is not null
    exec sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'xp_unpackcab'

if object_id('sp_repldone', 'local') is not null
    exec sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'sp_repldone'

if object_id('sp_repltrans', 'local') is not null
    exec sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'sp_repltrans'

if object_id('sp_replcounters', 'local') is not null
    exec sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'sp_replcounters'

if object_id('sp_replhelp', 'local') is not null
    exec sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'sp_replhelp'

if object_id('sp_replddlparser', 'local') is not null
    exec sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'sp_replddlparser'

if object_id('sp_replcmds', 'local') is not null
    exec sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'sp_replcmds'

if object_id('sp_replflush', 'local') is not null
    exec sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'sp_replflush'

if object_id('sp_replpostcmd', 'local') is not null
    exec sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'sp_replpostcmd'

if object_id('sp_replincrementlsn_internal', 'local') is not null
    exec sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'sp_replincrementlsn_internal'

if object_id('sp_replupdateschema', 'local') is not null
    exec sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'sp_replupdateschema'

if object_id('sp_replsetoriginator_internal', 'local') is not null
    exec sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'sp_replsetoriginator_internal'

if object_id('sp_replsetsyncstatus', 'local') is not null
    exec sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'sp_replsetsyncstatus'

if object_id('sp_replpostsyncstatus_int', 'local') is not null
        exec sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'sp_replpostsyncstatus_int'

if object_id('xp_dsninfo', 'local') is not null
    exec sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'xp_dsninfo'

if object_id('xp_enumdsn', 'local') is not null
    exec sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'xp_enumdsn'

if object_id('xp_oledbinfo', 'local') is not null
    exec sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'xp_oledbinfo'

if object_id('xp_repl_encrypt', 'local') is not null
    exec sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'xp_repl_encrypt'

if object_id('xp_repl_convert_encrypt', 'local') is not null
    exec sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'xp_repl_convert_encrypt'

if object_id('xp_repl_help_connect', 'local') is not null
    exec sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'xp_repl_help_connect'

if object_id('xp_replproberemsrv', 'local') is not null
    exec sys.sp_dropextendedproc 'xp_replproberemsrv'

go

--
-- Create table dbo.MSreplication_options in master if needed
--
if object_id(N'dbo.MSreplication_options', 'local') is null
BEGIN
    -- table does not exist
    raiserror('Creating table MSreplication_options',0,1)

    CREATE TABLE dbo.MSreplication_options 
    (
        optname sysname NOT NULL,
        value bit NOT NULL,
        major_version int NOT NULL,
        minor_version int NOT NULL,
        revision int NOT NULL,
        install_failures int NOT NULL
    )

    exec dbo.sp_MS_marksystemobject N'dbo.MSreplication_options'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- table exists 
    -- drop index if needed (this index was used in Sphinx)
    if exists (select * from sys.indexes where object_id = object_id(N'dbo.MSreplication_options')
                        and name = N'ucMSreplication_options')
    begin
        drop index dbo.MSreplication_options.ucMSreplication_options
    end
END
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MSreplication_options WHERE optname = 'transactional')
    INSERT INTO MSreplication_options VALUES
        ('transactional',0,0,0,0,0)
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MSreplication_options WHERE optname = 'merge')
    INSERT INTO MSreplication_options VALUES
        ('merge',0,0,0,0,0)
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MSreplication_options WHERE optname = 'security_model')
BEGIN
    DECLARE @major_version  int,
            @minor_version  int,
            @revision       int

    -- @@microsoftversion is set as 0xMMmmRR[RR] wher M=Major, m=minor and R=revision
    --  SELECT @major_version   = CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varbinary(4), @@microsoftversion), 1, 1)), 
    --      @minor_version  = CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varbinary(4), @@microsoftversion), 2, 1)),
    --      @revision       = CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varbinary(4), @@microsoftversion), 3, 2))
    SELECT @major_version   = 90,
            @minor_version  = 0,
            @revision       = 0

    INSERT INTO MSreplication_options (optname, value, major_version, minor_version, revision, install_failures) 
        VALUES ('security_model', 1, @major_version, @minor_version, @revision, 0)
END

UPDATE MSreplication_options
    SET major_version = 90
GO

-- Startup procs have to be created in master
if object_id('sp_MSrepl_startup', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure sp_MSrepl_startup  

raiserror('Creating procedure sp_MSrepl_startup', 0,1)
go

create procedure dbo.sp_MSrepl_startup
as
    exec sys.sp_MSrepl_startup_internal
go

exec master.dbo.sp_MS_marksystemobject sp_MSrepl_startup

-- If a distributor is installed, mark the sp as a startup sp. 
if exists (select * FROM master..sysservers WHERE  srvstatus & 8 <> 0)
    exec dbo.sp_procoption 'sp_MSrepl_startup', 'startup', 'true' 
go

if object_id('sp_MScleanupmergepublisher', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure sp_MScleanupmergepublisher
go

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON

raiserror('Creating procedure sp_MScleanupmergepublisher', 0,1)
go
create procedure dbo.sp_MScleanupmergepublisher
as
    exec sys.sp_MScleanupmergepublisher_internal
go

-- If there are any merge published databases installed on this server, 
-- mark sp_MScleanupmergepublisher as a startup proc

if exists (select * from master..sysdatabases where (category & 4) <> 0)
    exec dbo.sp_procoption 'sp_MScleanupmergepublisher', 'startup', 'true'

--
-- Functions that used to be created in master and have now moved to resource
-- use exec to drop, otherwise "drop function" gives syntax error on SQL 7, which did not have UDFs yet
--

if object_id('fn_varbintohexstr', 'local') is not null
     exec('drop function dbo.fn_varbintohexstr')

if object_id('fn_varbintohexsubstring', 'local') is not null
     exec('drop function dbo.fn_varbintohexsubstring')

go

--
-- procedures that used to be created in master and are obsolete now
-- drop the local procedures in master
--
if object_id(N'dbo.sp_addpublisher', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_addpublisher

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_fetchshowcmdsinput', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_fetchshowcmdsinput

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_getagentoffloadinfo', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_getagentoffloadinfo

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_gettypestring', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_gettypestring

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_helpmergecleanupwait', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_helpmergecleanupwait

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_helpsubscriptionjobname', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_helpsubscriptionjobname

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_mergecompletecleanup', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_mergecompletecleanup

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_mergepreparecleanup', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_mergepreparecleanup

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSaddpubtocontents', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSaddpubtocontents

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSareallcolumnscomputed', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSareallcolumnscomputed

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSchunkgeneration', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSchunkgeneration

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MScleanup_metadata', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MScleanup_metadata

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MScleanuptask', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MScleanuptask

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MScompletecleanup', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MScompletecleanup

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MScomputearticlescreationorder', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MScomputearticlescreationorder

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MScomputeunresolvedrefs', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MScomputeunresolvedrefs

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSdelete_specifiedcontents', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSdelete_specifiedcontents

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSdeletecontents', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSdeletecontents

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSdeletepushagent', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSdeletepushagent

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSenumchanges_direct', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSenumchanges_direct

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSenumchanges_pal', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSenumchanges_pal

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSenumpartialchanges_direct', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSenumpartialchanges_direct

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSenumpartialchanges_pal', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSenumpartialchanges_pal

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSexternalfkreferences', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSexternalfkreferences

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSget_subtypedatasrc', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSget_subtypedatasrc

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSgettypestringudt', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSgettypestringudt

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MShelpsubscriptionjobname', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MShelpsubscriptionjobname

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSinsertcontents', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSinsertcontents

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSis_col_replicated', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSis_col_replicated

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSload_replication_status', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSload_replication_status

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSmakedynsnapshotvws_longdef', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSmakedynsnapshotvws_longdef

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSpreparecleanup', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSpreparecleanup

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSquiescecheck', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSquiescecheck

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSquiesceforcleanup', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSquiesceforcleanup

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSquiescetriggersoff', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSquiescetriggersoff

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSquiescetriggerson', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSquiescetriggerson

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSreplcheck_connection', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSreplcheck_connection

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSscript_security', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSscript_security

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSscript_validate_subscription', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSscript_validate_subscription

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSscriptmvastable', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSscriptmvastable

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSscriptmvastableidx', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSscriptmvastableidx

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSscriptmvastablenci', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSscriptmvastablenci

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSscriptmvastablepkc', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSscriptmvastablepkc

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSsubst_filter_name', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSsubst_filter_name

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSupdate_replication_status', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSupdate_replication_status

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSupdatecontents', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSupdatecontents

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_replicationoption', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_replicationoption

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_replproberemoteserver', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_replproberemoteserver

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_replsetoriginator_pal', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_replsetoriginator_pal

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_verify_publication', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_verify_publication

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSarticletextcol', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSarticletextcol

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSexists_file', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSexists_file

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSfixlineagemismatch', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSfixlineagemismatch

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MStextcolstatus', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MStextcolstatus

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSread_resolver_clsid', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSread_resolver_clsid

if object_id(N'dbo.sp_MSsubscriptions', 'local') is not null
    drop procedure dbo.sp_MSsubscriptions

go
```

After I ran this, I was able to import my backed-up DB on the subscriber without error.